# Unhandled Runtime Error AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401 in next.js

Tags: javascript, redux, async-await, next.js, axios

I am using **Next.js**. I have created an **Axios** interceptor where a rejected Promise will be returned. But where there is a server-specific error that I need. **Next.js** is showing the error in the application like this.

[image]

And there is the code of the Axios interceptor and instance.

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from "../redux/store";
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

let token = "";
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const item = localStorage.getItem('key')
  token = item;
}
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: publicRuntimeConfig.backendURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    const { auth } = store.getState();
    if (auth.token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${auth.token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error)
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Also, I am using redux and there is the action.

```
import axios from "../../api/axios";
import { authConstants } from "../types";

export const login = (data) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: authConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST,
      });
      const res = axios.post("/user/login", data);
      if (res.status === 200) {
        dispatch({
          type: authConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, authConstants);
      dispatch({
        type: authConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE,
        payload: { error: error.response?.data?.error },
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Your response interceptors are completely redundant. What is it you actually want them to do?

Comment: @Phil I will work with the response interceptor later. I will check for any 401 or 403 status codes and then logout the user. But every time I will need the Promise.reject. Do you have any solution? And this is not showing in the production build. Everything is fine on the production build.

Comment: Are you asking how to write an [Axios interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)? It's not clear what your actual question is. If you want to handle specific error states, you definitely do not _"need the Promise.reject"_.

Comment: @Phil I am not asking how to write the axios interceptor. I can remove Promise.reject but in this case I need to change a lot in my code. Because in the redux I am getting the rejected promise by try catch.

Comment: _"I am not asking how to write the axios interceptor"_... then what **are** you asking?

Comment: @Phil did you see the screenshot on my question? I am getting errors in the front end in the next.js style. But I don't want to show an error like that.

Comment: Then handle the failed promises in your code. FYI you're missing `await` in `const res = axios.post("/user/login", data)`

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much. I was doing a very small mistake just for my careless behaviour. I should review my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here...

> ```js
> const res = axios.post("/user/login", data);
> ```

You're missing `await` to wait for the response

```js
const res = await axios.post("/user/login", data);
```

This fixes two things...

1. Your code now waits for the response and `res.status` on the next line will be defined
2. Any errors thrown by Axios (which surface as rejected promises) will trigger your `catch` block. Without the `await` this does not happen and any eventual promise failure bubbles up to the top-level Next.js error handler, resulting in the popup in your screenshot.